# CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition for background applications

Tags: macos, cgeventtap

I have an application that interprets trackpad events in the background (for all apps).

I'd like to be able to dis-associate the mouse from the cursor at certain times. CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition only works when my app is in the foreground.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Hello question from 5 years ago. I'm guessing there's still no valid solution?

Comment: I used `CGEventTapCreate` to tap into the mouse events and treat the ones that interested me, then `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition` to move the move the mouse back where I wanted it to be. Surprisingly, this worked perfectly without any flicker.